# Link Google automl translation custom model with glossary

Tags: google-cloud-platform, model, google-cloud-automl, machine-translation, glossary

I have built a custom translation model and a glossary using Google automl. This resulted in two different paths, one for using the model and a different one for the glossary.
I was wondering if it would be possible to link both model and glossary to get a single path to connect model+glossary with a different translation tool (in my case Wordbee). I am now able to connect the model but not the glossary.

I know I can use together model and glossary making a POST request and with a request JSON, but what I want is to integrate together model and corresponding glossary in an external tool with a single path if possible. Something like

```
projects/project-number/locations/us-central1/model+glossary-id
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can essentially just combine the JSON of the glossary and model requests.

The HTTP method and URL is the same.

https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/glossary#translate_v3_get_glossary-drest

> HTTP method and URL:
>
> ```
> POST https://translation.googleapis.com/v3/projects/PROJECT_NUMBER_OR_ID/locations/us-central1:translateText
> ```
>
> Request JSON body:
>
> ```
> {
>  "sourceLanguageCode": "en",
>  "targetLanguageCode": "ru",
>  "contents": "Dr. Watson, please discard your trash. You've shared > unsolicited email with me. Let's talk about spam and importance ranking in a confidential mode.",
>  "glossaryConfig": {
>    "glossary": "projects/project-number/locations/us-> central1/glossaries/glossary-id",
>    "ignoreCase": BOOLEAN
>  }
> }
> ```

https://cloud.google.com/translate/automl/docs/predict#using-translate-api

> HTTP method and URL:
>
> ```
> POST https://translation.googleapis.com/v3/projects/project-number-or-id/locations/us-central1:translateText
> ```
>
> Request JSON body:
>
> ```
> {
>  "model": "projects/project-number-or-id/locations/us-central1/models/TRL1395675701985363739",
>  "sourceLanguageCode": "en",
>  "targetLanguageCode": "ru",
>  "contents": ["Dr. Watson, please discard your trash. You've shared unsolicited email with me.
>  Let's talk about spam and importance ranking in a confidential mode."]
> }
> ```

You will end up with something like this.

```
{
  "model": "projects/project-number-or-id/locations/us-central1/models/TRL1395675701985363739",
  "glossaryConfig": {
   "glossary": "projects/project-number/locations/us-> central1/glossaries/glossary-id",
   "ignoreCase": BOOLEAN
  }
  "sourceLanguageCode": "en",
  "targetLanguageCode": "ru",
  "contents": ["Dr. Watson, please discard your trash. You've shared unsolicited email with me.
  Let's talk about spam and importance ranking in a confidential mode."]
}
```